# Using multiple custom event as triggers in HTMX, can I identify which of the triggers is being used?

Tags: javascript, python, django, htmx, intercooler.js

I am using HTMX in my Django project to change elements in a form depending on previous selections.
At some point I use a custom event and listen for it as indicated in solution 3 here: https://htmx.org/examples/update-other-content/

Everything works as expected, also when using two triggers separated by a comma.

However, I would like to pass a header, the value of which depends on the event being used as trigger. Trigger foo -> header A, trigger bar -> header B.
Below is some code that should help understand.

```
<div hx-get="{% url 'someurl' %}" 
     hx-trigger="foo from:body, bar from:body" 
     hx-target="#sometarget"
     hx-swap="outerHTML"
     hx-headers='{"someheader":"foo_value"}' OR '{"someheader":"bar_value"}'>
```

So far, I have tried:

- putting target.value as header value (you can use it as trigger filter, so I thought it might work in hx-headers too)
- Passing headers or context variables in the view that causes the trigger to go off, so that then I can use Django's {% if %} in the template. But they don't get here because that view renders a different part of the template, and this is just being triggered because it listens for the event on the body due to event bubbling

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTMX provides the [`htmx:configRequest`](https://htmx.org/events/#htmx:configRequest) event, where we can inspect and alter the payload before HTMX dispatches the request. The triggering event is located in the `evt.detail.triggeringEvent.type` property, the header object is at `evt.detail.headers`. So we can add a custom header depending on the triggering event by including the following JS snippet on the specific page:

```
<script>
document.body.addEventListener('htmx:configRequest', (evt) => {
  if (evt.detail.triggeringEvent.type === 'foo') {
    evt.detail.headers['someheader'] = 'foo_value'
  }
  if (evt.detail.triggeringEvent.type === 'bar') {
    evt.detail.headers['someheader'] = 'bar_value'
  }
})
</script>
```